# Akka.Net: Reactive Streams over the network

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-streams

I am trying to implement both the Source as origin and the Sink as remote, and then the Sink as origin and the Source as remote, Type 1 and Type 2 workflows within the [AkkaStreamsModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/offBq.png) Respectively.

Type 1 creates a `SourceRef` and passes this to the remote actor as an exposed source of incoming data to the sink actor. Type 2 creates a `SinkRef` and passes this to the remote actor as an exposed sink to start sending data to. For further explanation, I have uploaded both Type 1 ([AkkaStreams](https://github.com/BrettGFleischer/AkkaStreams)) and Type 2 ([AkkaStreamsFaulty](https://github.com/BrettGFleischer/AkkaStreamsFaulty)) workflows onto GitHub.

The Type 1 workflow was set up and works correctly, however, the Type 2 workflow is faulty. I have narrowed the problem down to the `Receive<PrepareUpload>()` method within the `DataReceiver` actor. Upon succesful creation of the sink, the flow and the sink are sent (via a `MeasurementsSinkReady` message) to the source actor using the `PipeTo()` method.

Can anyone indicate where I may be going wrong within the Type 2 workflow? I have exhausted all other options ([Akka.Net Documentation](https://getakka.net/articles/streams/introduction.html); [Akka.Net Gitter](https://gitter.im/akkadotnet/akka.net), various blogs and videos etc). I am unsure of where to go from here, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

*Edit (Added extra information as per [Bartosz Sypytkowski's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2721139/bartosz-sypytkowski) comment)*

*The data is never sent between the two actors remotely, that is the problem. Using Type 1, a `SourceRef` is established and sent to the remote actor. The remote actor receives this message. However, for Type 2, the `SinkRef` is created but never reaches the remote actor. 
Therefore, I assume the problem is with the generation of the `SinkRef` or the `PipeTo()` method. This is because if you send a message between the actors it works, but if the message is conditional on the `SinkRef` being setup correctly, then something went wrong in the setup.*

Comment: You didn't tell what issues did you encounter.

Comment: The data is never sent between the two actors remotely, that is the problem. Using Type 1, a `SourceRef` is established and sent to the remote actor. The remote actor receives this message. However, for Type 2, the `SinkRef` is created but never reaches the remote actor. 

Therefore, I assume the problem is with the generation of the `SinkRef` or the `PipeTo()` method. This is because if you send a message between the actors it works, but if the message is conditional on the `SinkRef` being setup correctly, then something went wrong in the setup.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I am out of ideas and could really use some help.

Comment: Do you have any code gist/snippet you can share that we can use to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hi @Greg, please see the GitHub pages above that contain the problems, [AkkaStreamsFaulty](https://github.com/BrettGFleischer/AkkaStreamsFaulty). As discussed above, the problem has been narrowed down to the `Receive<PrepareUpload>()` method within the `DataReceiver` actor.

Comment: I did a pull request on your [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BrettGFleischer/AkkaStreamsFaulty/pull/1) on how to fix it.

Comment: Hi @Greg I've made comments on your pull request as to why it was not a solution. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: In a stream, for every sink, you will need a source. What your original code missing is a `Souce` for the sink to source from, so the problem was not in `PipeTo`.

Comment: I understand that a `Sink` needs a `Source`, the `Source` is in the remote actor system. Hence the title `Akka.Net: Reactive Streams over the network`. Once the `Sink` has been set up correctly, the `SinkRef` is sent to the `DataSource` actor (like so [SinkRef over the network](https://getakka.net/images/sink-ref-animation.gif)) and then the remote `Source` actor can send info to the `Sink`.

Comment: It turns out that, with the current serializer implementation, this can't really be done. The problem is that `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer` could not handle `SinkRef` serialization. If you want to do this, you'd have to send a naked `SinkRef`. So, as a fix, instead of sending the `ISinkRef<string>` inside the `MeasurementsSinkReady` class, try sending an `ISinkRef<string>`.
This feature will be added as part of the 1.5.0 roadmap.

Comment: Great @Greg, May I get a link to this? For tracking purposes.

Comment: It is currently logged as this: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/pull/4425

Comment: Hi @Greg, just wanted to know how and when to follow up on the issue?

Comment: Hi @Greg, what other avenues might I take to get the issue bumped by the Akka.Net team?

Comment: Hi @Brett, we're putting this issue into the next Akka.NET sprint, which will happen 2 weeks from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the Akka.Streams implementation - as of v1.4.14 this issue has been fixed: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/4421

Comment: Did test the fix, can confirm that it is now working. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it!